# How to parse non-json messages in logstash with grok filter

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, pipeline, logstash-grok

I am trying to put logs messages from all containers to elastic search but I suggest a lot of them not in JSON format I trying to parse them with simple grok filter parameters but I see a lot of container names in final msg and grokparsefail status[image]

```
 if [type] == "filebeat-docker-logs" {

    grok {
      match => {
        "message" => "\[%{WORD:containerName}\] %{GREEDYDATA:message_remainder}"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use following grok pattern :

```
(?<containerName>[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+).*?(?<timestamp>%{YEAR}\/%{MONTHNUM}\/%{MONTHDAY} %{TIME}) %{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

it works[image]